# c# mongodb find derived object with Builders

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two collections, which stores two different objects (each one represent an object) that inherited from the same object.

Something like:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string name = "someName";
}

public class FirstClass : BaseClass { ... }
public class SecondClass : BaseClass { ... }

var FirstCollection = mongo.GetCollection<FirstClass>("First");
var SecondClass =    mongo.GetCollection<SecondClass>("Second");
```

Now, I have a query to run over the two collection, using only the common fields. 
I want to use the same query, using the "MongoDB.Driver.Builders".

Something like:

```
var filter = Builders<BaseClass>.Filter.Where(y => y.name == "someName");
var result = FirstCollection.Find(filter);
```

Any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

With the following setup you can do it more or less the same as you already do. This is the context:

```
public class Context
{
    public const string DATABASE_NAME = "Test";
    public const string FIRST_COLLECTION_NAME = "FirstCollection";
    public const string SECOND_COLLECTION_NAME = "SecondCollection";

    private static readonly IMongoClient _client;
    private static readonly IMongoDatabase _database;
    static Context()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDbServer"];
        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        _database = _client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    public IMongoClient Client => _client;

    public IMongoCollection<First> FirstCollection =>
        _database.GetCollection<First>(FIRST_COLLECTION_NAME);

    public IMongoCollection<Second> SecondCollection =>
        _database.GetCollection<Second>(SECOND_COLLECTION_NAME);
}
```

The `First`, `Second`, and `Base` classes are the same as yours. Then you can find your documents like this:

```
var context = new Context();
var builder = Builders<First>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Name, "Paul");
//You can insert like this:
//context.FirstCollection.InsertOne(new First(){Name = "Paul", Age = 33});
var result = context.FirstCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

**Update**

After your edit, the only way I can think of is this:

```
var result = context.FirstCollection.Find(x=> x.Name == "Paul").ToList();
```