# How to send find request to mongodb from c # via mongo driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a task of finding a document in a collection that contains a specific video (by the name of the video). In the mongodb client, I manually send a request:

```
db.getCollection('ConstructorPages').find( 
{$or: [
    {$and: [{"mainBlocks.columns.innerElements.value.url" :
    /.806fa33d3_61b51d72d.mp4./}, 
{"mainBlocks.columns.innerElements.name" :"Video"} ]}, 
    {$and: [{"rightBlocks.columns.innerElements.value.url" :
    /.806fa33d3_61b51d72d.mp4./}, 
{"rightBlocks.columns.innerElements.name" :"Video"} ]}
]} )
```

How can I implement the same request in C # using the mongo driver? I dug in the direction of writing filters to select documents. But the given code doesn't work as I expect:

```
//fileName = "806fa33d3_61b51d72d.mp4"
public ConstructorPageDocument GetPageByFileName(string fileName) 
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument("mainBlocks.columns.innerElements.value.url", fileName);

    return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Upd: I did not take into account that I was performing a search query by occurrence (analogous 'like' in sql). In the end, the following code worked for me:

```
public SchoolConstructorPageDocument GetPageByFileName(string fileName)
{
   var filter = new 
       BsonDocument("mainBlocks.columns.innerElements.value.url",  
                     new BsonRegularExpression(fileName));

   return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? NOTE: You added only one condition from the first example. Also, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050726/c-sharp-mongodb-find-derived-object-with-builders

Comment: Yes, I deliberately shortened the C # request for the test. But I did not take into account that I was performing a search query by occurrence (analogous to like in sql). UPD above